# insert text after specified lines in a file

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I need support to do the following task for a file contains around 5000 lines.

input

```
    cp abc/P_10_10A.pdb lig.pdb
    cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
    cp abc/run.pl .
    ./run.pl 

    cp abc/P_10_11A.pdb lig.pdb
    cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
    cp abc/run.pl .
    ./run.pl

    cp abc/P_10_11B.pdb lig.pdb
    cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
    cp abc/run.pl .
    ./run.pl
```

output

```
    cp abc/P_10_10A.pdb lig.pdb
    cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
    cp abc/run.pl .
    ./run.pl
    mv *.* P_10_10A

    cp abc/P_10_11A.pdb lig.pdb
    cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
    cp abc/run.pl .
    ./run.pl
    mv *.* P_10_11A

    cp abc/P_10_11B.pdb lig.pdb
    cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
    cp abc/run.pl .
    ./run.pl
    mv *.* P_10_11B
```

I could add mv *.* as follows..

```
    sed '0~4 a\mv *.*  \'       text_file.sh
```

How can I do the rest? thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to work in multiline mode or using holding buffer to keep the folder name. Also, with a `a` you can't modify the content of this appended line, it's only in ouptut stream, not in current working buffer

Comment: Are the leading spaces in your data really there? Are the blank lines really there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One liner**

```
awk -F'[/.]' '!s && /cp/{s=$2;}s && /\.\/run\.pl/{$0=$0 RS "mv *.* "s;s=""}1' file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F'[/.]' '                    # -F set field sep forward slash or dot
      !s && /cp/{                 # if s is not set and cp word found
             s=$2                 # Assign second column value to s
      }
      s && /\.\/run\.pl/{         # when s is set and ./run.pl found
        $0 = $0 RS "mv *.* "s     # append current record with mv *.* value to s
        s=""                      # Reset s
      }1                          # perform default operation print $0
     ' file                       # Input file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat f
cp abc/P_10_10A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl 

cp abc/P_10_11A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl

cp abc/P_10_11B.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[/.]' '!s && /cp/{s=$2}s && /\.\/run\.pl/{$0 = $0 RS "mv *.* "s; s=""}1' f
cp abc/P_10_10A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl 
mv *.* P_10_10A

cp abc/P_10_11A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_11A

cp abc/P_10_11B.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_11B
```

**For space modify this statement**

```
$0=$0 RS "    mv *.* "s;
```

Comment: Did not understand the reason for down vote, down voter please let me know what's wrong here

Comment: I didn't downvoted the answer but given output doesn't contains `space` before lines starting with `mv *.* P_10_11B`.

Comment: @AbhiNickz : If you need space please modify like this `$0=$0 RS "    mv *.* "s;` , put space just before `mv *.*`

Answer (score 1):

a sed version

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*cp /,/^[[:blank:]]*\./ {
      H
      /^[[:blank:]]*\./!d
      s/.*//;x
      s#^\(\(.[[:blank:]]*\)cp \)\([^[:blank:]]*/\([^[:blank:]]*\)\)\(\.pdb.*\)#\1\3\5\2mv *.* \4#
      }' YourFile
```

info:

- proceed by paragraph (`/^[[:blank:]]*cp /,/^[[:blank:]]*\./`) from first cp until ./
- add each line to holding buffer (`H`)
- if not last line of paragraph, delete the line from current work buffer (so do nothing more and cycle with a read of next line) (`/^[[:blank:]]*\./!d`)
- empty the line and swap buffer content (`s/.*//;x`)
- extract the *file name* of the paragraph and add it to the end with the `mv` info (`s#^\(\(.[[:blank:]]*\)cp \)\([^[:blank:]]*/\([^[:blank:]]*\)\)\(\.pdb.*\)#\1\3\5\2mv *.* \4#`). This regex is the tricky one with some special info

  - there is a new line as 1st character (due to first `H` and not `h`)
  - i use several subgroup to use them as pattern easily like the second group, a new line and first series of space (if any) that is included in 1st group
- let sed print the result

  - modified paragraph
  - untouched line like *empty* lines between paragraph

---

an awk version

```
awk -F '[/.]' '
   /cp / {f[n++]=$2}
   /\.\/run/ {print;sub( /\..*/, "mv *.* " f[n=0])}
   7
   ' YourFile
```

info:

- use `.` and `/` as field separator (`-F '[/.]'`)
- for each line with cp, keep folder name in and incremental array (first index = 0) (`/cp / {f[n++]=$2}`)
- for each line with `./run`: (`/\.\/run/ {print;sub( /\..*/, "mv *.* " f[n=0])}`)

  - print the line
  - replace the text part with `mv ...`
  - the good name is always f[0]
  - reset the index in same time (`n=0`)
- print the line `7`

Answer (score 1):

This Perl approach expects the path to the input file on the command line and sends the output to stdout

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

local $/ = "";

while ( <> ) {
    if ( m| \b cp \s+ (?: \w+ / )* (\w+) |x ) {
        my $pdb = $1;
        s/ .* \S \K /\nmv *.* $pdb/xs;
    }
    print;
}
```

#### output

```bash
cp abc/P_10_10A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_10A 

cp abc/P_10_11A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_11A

cp abc/P_10_11B.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_11B
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for the given `data` in `perl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $IN, "<", "test";
open my $OUT, ">", "test_new";
my $insert;
while (my $line = <$IN>){
    chomp($line);

    if($line =~ m/cp abc\/(.*).pdb lig.pdb$/){
        $insert = $1;
    }

    if($line =~ m/    \.\/run\.pl/){
        $line = $line."\n".'    mv *.* '.$insert;
    }
    print $OUT $line."\n";
}
close $IN;
close $OUT;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cp abc/P_10_10A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_10A

cp abc/P_10_11A.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_11A

cp abc/P_10_11B.pdb lig.pdb
cp abc/protein.pdbqt .
cp abc/run.pl .
./run.pl
mv *.* P_10_11B
```

Comment: I can't account for the downvote, but your code is very non-Perlish. It also matches exact amounts of whitespace, when the leading spaces in the OP's data probably aren't even there. Your second `if` should also be an `elseif`. Put it up on [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want a thorough analysis.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for your given analysis, I will keep this in mind.